# How to wrap wordpress shortcode in a div

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created following shortcode function to call a menu on a specific location on page

```
function servicesmenu() {
    return wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'services_nav', 'menu_id' => 'servicesmenu') );
}
add_shortcode('servicesMenu', 'servicesmenu');
```

Above code is working fine. But when i tried to wrap the shortcode in a DIV it's not wrapping, the menu generated by shortcode is coming before div id="services_rightarea"

```
<div id="services_rightarea">
    <!-- other content here -->
    [servicesMenu]
</div>
```

Any solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `wp_nav_menu` echos by default.  You need to capture this echo in a variable and return it.  This can be done with [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
function servicesmenu() {

    // Start output buffering
    ob_start(); 

    // The echo of this call is caught in the buffer
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu_id' => 'servicesmenu');

    // Capture contents of buffer in a variable
    $menu = ob_get_contents();

    // End buffering
    ob_end_clean();

    // Return your menu and bask in the warming glow of working code
    return $menu;
}
add_shortcode('servicesMenu', 'servicesmenu');
```

**Edit:** I just noticed that you're also using the `theme_location` property.  This will try to insert the result of the `wp_nav_menu` call into `servicesmenu` menu, which was registered with [register_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu).

Take the `theme_location` parameter out and the output buffering will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it solved my problem :)
If if remove theme_location propery, it's picking up another nav menu, but output is working fine with the code you provided with theme_location added in it.

Comment: @alok I dont understand when there is theme_location than why are you using shortcode

Comment: @PeachLabs i need to use the navigation as a list inside the content of page. I can not directly use PHP code there.